# angularjs ng-resource Asynchronously Upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am uploading about 10 photos at a time (photos ranging unto 800kb - 1000kb per photo).

My issue is, that the app crashes after about 5 seconds.

How do I upload the photos Asynchronously and maybe improve the performance of the app?

**Controller**

```
  appcon.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaCamera, $ionicPopup, PostImg){


      $scope.postData = [];

              var truckid = "%" + window.localStorage['truckid'] + "%";

      $scope.start = function() {

      document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

        var options = {
          quality: 200,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,                                  
          allowEdit: true,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 1000,
          targetHeight: 1000,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
          correctOrientation:true
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

        var file = imageData;
          $scope.postData.push({file});

        }, function(err) {

        console.log('4 error');
        });

      }, false);



     }

     $scope.upload = function() {
       var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
         title: 'Continue?',
         template: 'Are you sure you want to Send Images?'
       });

       confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
         if(res) {
          $scope.postData.push({truckid});
          var post = new PostImg($scope.postData);
          post.$save(function(postObject) {

            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                              title: 'Images Send !',
                              buttons: [{ 
                              text: 'Continue with Check In?',
                              type: 'button-positive'
                              }]
                            });
                            alertPopup.then(function(res) {
                            });  
            });
          }  

          else {
                  console.log('You are not sure');
               }
        });
       }
      })
```

**Factory**

```
appcon.factory('PostImg', function($resource) {
 return $resource('http://192.168.0.1/Service.svc/BOB');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try cordova-plugin-file-transfer. Please note that it will work only in phone.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Comment: I am using a REST service and $resource is working great with my service. Also I did use file transfer but it does not work as well on IOS as I would like it too. My Issue is, everything is uploaded at ones so I need to upload them asynchronously.

Comment: destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
Loading all pictures as dataurl in memory will take lot of memory and will cause your app crash. So only way is save it to phone storage and transfer them. For that you will need to use some native plugins. I can suggest no other way. Please do some research and share your findings, so that it can help others. Thanks..